# How to get hostname of Redis master from Sentinel

Tags: node.js, ssl, redis, redis-sentinel, ioredis

I am facing a problem with Sentinel TLS. So the issue is in the background I have a node application trying to connect to Redis using sentinel. When we request a master address to sentinel it's returning IP instead of HOSTNAME so the node is trying to connect with IP and server returning error saying IP doesn't match the certificate.

How can I get the hostname from sentinel? or do I need to convert IP to Name at node module?

I found https://redis.io/topics/sentinel that sentinel doesn't allow to use of hostnames in the config.